Laravel join - return relation with prefered column value first
I am running a query with joins in Laravel.
A post has multiple translations.
Comment::select('comments.post_id', 'posts_translations.title AS post_title')
    ->join('posts', 'comments.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
    ->join('posts_translations', 'posts.id', '=', 'posts_translations.post_id')
    ->groupBy('comments.id')

The comment table



id
comment
post_id




1
Lorem Ipsum
1



The posts table



id
author_id




1
1



The posts_translations table



id
post_id
title
locale




1
1
Title en
en


2
1
Titel nl
nl



When I do {{ $comment->post_title }} it always shows "Title en". I would like to get "Title nl" when app()->getLocale() is 'nl'. How do I do that with a query? Sometimes a post can have no locale for 'nl' and should return "Title en".  The query has to be a magic sortby so to say. Because the join always returns the first result it should sort it by PRIORITY on a magic way.
I have tried the following too:
->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN posts_translations.locale = '".app()->getLocale()."' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END");

and
->orderByRaw("FIELD(posts_translations.locale, '".app()->getLocale()."', 'en')")

but order by is done AFTER groupBy. So it's not working...

You could add a where clause to your query.
$comments = Comment::query()
    ->select('comments.post_id', 'posts_translations.title AS post_title')
    ->join('posts', 'comments.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
    ->join('posts_translations', 'posts.id', '=', 'posts_translations.post_id')
    ->where('locale', app()->getLocale())
    ->get()

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    // $comment->post_id
    // $comment->post_title
}

Or if you want to use accessors and relationships you could make it an accessor in the Post model.
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function post_translations(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PostTranslation::class);
    }

    protected function postTitle(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: function () {
                $this->loadMissing('post_translations');

                return $this->post_translations->firstWhere('locale', app()->getLocale())?->title ?? 'untranslated';
        );
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function post(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}

$comments = Comment::query()
    ->with('post.post_translations')
    ->get();

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    // $comment->post_id
    // $comment->post->post_title
}


I should make my question more clear, the query has to give PRIORITY to a language, but return the other if not present, a magic sortby so to say
